# Agghhh! UPS Back-Up, Laptop Charger, Sparks

Tags: laptop, power-supply, hardware-failure, power, ups

Boy… ok. This is so frustrating! Ok so, I've been getting a whole lot of problems with the electrical grid here lately: spikes, surges, lows, brown-outs, all kinds of problems, it's terrible, short-circuiting things left and right. I have been afraid to even plug my laptop (Toshiba Satellite L300 Series) in at all to charge it. So I wanted to get a really good surge protector/battery back-up to protect it (it's really important to me, I'm a sentimental sort, and I don't *want* to just upgrade to a new laptop like everyone tells me, I'm very attached to this one!). So I do some research, the APC Back-UPS Network 40 450VA Battery Back-Up System BN4001 is the one I end up going with.

So I do all the stuff to get it set up, attach the battery, get it plugged in, turned on, all that, I go to actually try to plug my notebook's charger (which is, at this time, actually plugged in to the computer itself, mind you) into the UPS, and… it won't go in, can't get it to fit, there's sparks blasting out, what is going on here? I tried to plug in a different thing, with a three-prong plug, which seems to be the only thing it's designed to take, but my laptop power cord has a two-prong plug which I just can't get in, and what concerns me even more now is the sparking, does this mean my computer will have been damaged? I fear the worst. Please help, I would really, really appreciate any guidance right about now. At the end of my rope currently with all this! :(

Here are some images, which were requested to help visualize what I'm talking about: this is the UPS (not the exact model I have but really similar)  http://sishardware.com/imgs/a/a/t/j/t/apc_back___ups_es_550_ups_330_watt_8_outlets_4_surge_be550r_easy_set_up_1_lgw.jpg and this is the laptop power cord http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41Ef8gJpFsL.SX300.jpg

Comment: We can't tell you if trying to force a plug into another plug damaged your laptop.  We can tell you to stop doing that if you don't want to damage your laptop.  Are you sure the product you purchased supports the plug in your country?

Comment: Yes, of course I'm sure, both my device and the company that makes the product are all using American plugs! Obviously I have stopped doing it but I REALLY hope someone can tell me, why it won't accept a two-prong plug and if those sparks likely mean my computer was damaged… this is egregious, a device I purchased specifically to protect my computer from unforeseen damage, actually possibly causing it! :(

Comment: Your house is wired using American plugs?  Because the third pin is ground, if you are getting sparks, that indicates UPS isn't grounded.  A screenshot of the UPS and the plug your trying to use might be helpful.

Comment: I'm surprised no one has mentioned that some two-pronged plus are polarized and will only insert one way (one blade is slightly wider than the other). Have you tried rotating it 180 degrees? Seems like a stupid thing to suggest, but there it is. The sparks might be nothing but intermittent contact with the service voltage and capacitors in the power supply charging up (in-rush current). Hard to tell with the information given, though. Be careful. Maybe post some pictures of the plug/receptacle.

Comment: I don't understand… @Ramhound I get that the third pin is the ground… but it's not the plug on the UPS that's two-pronged, it's only the one for the computer. So the UPS has three pins, so logically, it *would* be grounded, right?

Comment: @Steve Yes, the plug for the computer adapter definitely *is* polarized, I have tried flipping it both ways, which I think may be part of the problem why the sparks were occurring. Either way I tried inserting it, the UPS wouldn't accept the two-pinned plug, which makes no sense to me, since, shouldn't those two plugs be the same shape whether there is a ground pin or not? I read every single piece of documentation that came with the UPS and not *one* mention about only accepting 3-pronged plugs!

Comment: Here are some images, which were requested to help visualize what I'm talking about: this is the UPS http://thumbs2.ebaystatic.com/d/l225/m/m5XIFMU33NRgrU6RMECaBSA.jpg
and this is the laptop power cord http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41Ef8gJpFsL._SX300_.jpg

Comment: Try using an adapter.  There exists adapters that will convert a 2-prong plug into a 3-prong plug.  The first image you provided isn't helpful.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to check the outlet the ups is plugged in to for proper polarity and grounding. but I see minor sparks frequently when I plug my 2 prong plug into a wall socket. Not fireworks, but a minor spark.

Comment: Thanks, Ramhound and SqlACID. @Ramhound I did actually figure out a workaround for the 2-prong/3-prong plug problem: I just plugged another surge strip (which has a 3-prong plug) into the UPS, then plugged my *computer into the surge strip*, and that seems to have solved the problem. My bigger concern now is about whether my computer was damaged by my initial attempt(s)!

Comment: I can't see how you could have damaged anything.

Comment: Provided you didn't actually try to force it, its unlikely, but we can't help actually determine if there is damage based on the information provided.  We would only be guessing.

Comment: Okay, thanks so much for all your help, everyone. I don't know. I thought I might have heard like a little bit of a popping sound coming from the computer or the wire when I was trying to plug it in, but I think that sometimes happens anyway when I first plug it in if it's been off or in sleep mode for awhile. Thanks everyone! I think I will ask a new question for that, though.